# Excel VBA - select last used columns

Tags: excel, vba

I want to select the last column and 2nd last column in my spreadsheet.

I've found my last column by:

```
LastColumn = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find("*", [a1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
    On Error GoTo 0
```

Then I'm trying to use the LastColumn to select from the 2nd last column to the last column and copy and paste.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(LastColumn - 1:LastColumn).Select
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Can someone please help and to what I may have gone wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(LastColumn - 1).Select`

**EDIT**: thanks Doug for pointing out my error...

`Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(LastColumn - 1).Resize(,2).Select`

Comment: Tim, HLB is trying to select the last two columns, I believe.